# Neovim doesn't refresh autocomplete suggestions after I delete characters with backspace

Tags: neovim

I have installed coc.nvim for autocomplete suggestions. When I press backspace key to remove a character dropdown list disappears and I have to press tab key everytime to trigger dropdown list. How can I set it to trigger dropdown list automatically even if I delete characters like in vscode?

[My nvim config Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLBqg.png)

Comment: I'm a beginner with neovim but my config seems to be working, do you use neovim lsp built in feature ? Can you share your settings ?

Comment: yes of course I've added my init.vim screenshot. You will see the link. If not then refresh the page. I would really appreciate your help

Comment: I switched my config to use lua :/ but if you are interesed i still can link you my dotfiles repository so you can inspire yourself with my neovim config, my lsp config is very strong, great autocompletion and what you are asking for too but i'll try to find an answer for your .vimrc

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try lua if nothing helps.

Comment: Sorry, i could not manage to find an anwser but here is my dotfiles with neovim if you want inspiration, it is ganular and well splitted so you can understand https://github.com/vrouilhac/dotfiles/tree/master/neovim

Comment: Now I realize that it is pretty hard for me to set things up from ground zero at this point. And unexpectedly Lunarvim has happened to be pretty good. All essential things are preinstalled and I haven't met any errors or bugs yet. it feels like I have Neovim on steroids